# How to convert three graphs made in tabbar view into scrollable view?

Tags: flutter

```
return MaterialApp(
  home: DefaultTabController(
    length: 3,
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff1976d2),
        //backgroundColor: Color(0xff308e1c),
        bottom: TabBar(
          indicatorColor: Color(0xff9962D0),
          tabs: [
            Tab(
              icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidChartBar),
            ),
            Tab(icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.chartPie)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.chartLine)),
          ],
        ),
        title: Text('Flutter Charts'),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Direct Emissions by lpg-cooking, lpg-lab  and diesel (in kg)',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    Expanded(
                      child: charts.BarChart(
                        _seriesData,
                        animate: true,
                        barGroupingType: charts.BarGroupingType.stacked,
                        behaviors: [new charts.SeriesLegend()],
                        animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'CO2 produced by electricity',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                      SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                      Expanded(
                         child:Stack(
                          children:<Widget>[
                           Container(
                           //color: Colors.blue,
                           height: 300.0,
                           width: 300.0,
                           child: dpc,
                         ),
                        Container(
                          // color: Colors.blue,
                          height: 300.0,
                          width: 300.0,
                          child: PieChart(dataMap: dataMap, showLegends: false,),
                        )
                        ],
                           ),
                      ),
                  ],
                      ),
                      ),
                ),
              ),
            ),

          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(
              child: Center(
                child:Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'CO2 in kg produced by vehicles',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    Expanded(
                      child: charts.LineChart(
                          _seriesLineData,
                          defaultRenderer: new charts.LineRendererConfig(
                              includeArea: true, stacked: true),
                          animate: true,
                          animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                          behaviors: [
                            new charts.SeriesLegend(),
                            new charts.ChartTitle('Months',
                                behaviorPosition: charts.BehaviorPosition.bottom,
                                titleOutsideJustification:charts.OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea),
                          ]
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, I'm thinking that you need to wrap your Container consists of several widgets inside SingleChildScrollView. Remember what ever the widgets, that you are building in a screen and you want them to scroll. Use SinglechildScrollView as top parent and add the remaining child widgets wrapped together inside a container and add this to SinglechildScrollView as a child object.

If my solution resolved your problem, please accept it as useful or just add your comments regarding your issue. I will definitely try to sort this out. Next time, please add the screenshot of your app to elaborate more about the problem. Thank you.... Happy learning

Comment: see I clearly, mentioned right in my comment. If you doesn't feel my answer as right. Don't make it as not useful, it will downgrade my reputation. If you can able to comment in a polite way, I will definitely help you with the solution. This kind of response doesn't make right what you feel.

Comment: If you really feel my answer was useful, please give me your valuable vote for my answer as useful. It will helpful for me to answer more questions for other learners. Thank you. Feel free to reach out to me on my email hscharan2010@gmail.com, if you have any queries. I'm one of the speaker at GDG Hyderabad and currently we are running a bootcamp on Flutter for a month long.

Comment: I tried doing using SingleChildScrollView but its not working

Comment: If possible can you share your complete source code through GitHub, I will run the App and can provide you the solution for sure. I want to check while running it where it was missing. @sneharao

Comment: Okay sure .... https://github.com/sneha37rao/flutter_code/blob/master/FlutterAnimatedCharts1/homepage.dart  , Please don't commit changes if you get the errors reach us to me on stackoverflow

Comment: @sneharao I have downloaded your code from GitHub repo. So many things were missing from the file. Please check your code once, there is no Manifest file and no config file to start the main page.